# Neovim: error checking my provider's health

Tags: neovim

when i run `checkhealth provider` i get the following error, i installed neovim with node: `npm install -g neovim`

```
provider: health#provider#check
========================================================================
  - ERROR: Failed to run healthcheck for "provider" plugin. Exception:
    function health#check[20]..health#provider#check[5]..<SNR>152_check_node, line 20
    Vim(if):E117: Unknown function: provider#node#can_inspect
```